# javascript ternary operator to increase or subtract value

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

The only difference in the following code are the **-** and **+** symbols used to increase or subtract the value.

```
if( that.hasClass('prev') ){
    $('.elem').scrollLeft( $('.elem').scrollLeft()-(0.1*factor) );
}
else if( that.hasClass('next') ){
    $('.elem').scrollLeft( $('.elem').scrollLeft()+(0.1*factor) );
}
```

I would like to know how to convert the code in a small ternary statement, is it possible?

Comment: Note that there are *two tests* being made - a single application of the ternary operator only makes *one* test.

Comment: `$('.element')[0].scrollLeft += cond ? 0.1 : -0.1;`

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to test both classes ("next" and "prev"), you can factor out the logic:

```
var mul = that.hasClass("prev") ? -1 :
          that.hasClass("next") ? 1 :
          0;

$(".elem").scrollLeft($(".elem").scrollLeft() + mul * 0.1 * factor);
```

You could turn that into a jQuery function if you felt particularly energetic:

```
$.fn.scrollDir = function() {
  return  that.hasClass("prev") ? -1 :
          that.hasClass("next") ? 1 :
          0;
};

$(".elem").scrollLeft($(".elem").scrollLeft() + that.scrollDir() * 0.1 * factor);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this the following should work:

```
$('.elem').scrollLeft($('.elem').scrollLeft()+(0.1*factor*(that.hasClass('prev') ? -1 : that.hasClass('next') ? 1 : 0)))
```

But for clarity, I'd probably leave it as you have written.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
(that.hasClass('prev')) ? $('.elem').scrollLeft( $('.elem').scrollLeft()-(0.1*factor) ) : $('.elem').scrollLeft( $('.elem').scrollLeft()+(0.1*factor) );
```

Comment: It's quite likely that jslint/hint would complain about seeing an expression where a statement was expected, and in this case, it would be as reasonable thing to complain about, since you've just replaced the `if` with the `?`, which is less readable, In the process, you've also changed the meaning of the program, because the original checked for `next`, but you've removed that check.